# FHIR Client - How do I create a "valueReference"

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I am using the NuGet package Hl7.Fhir.R4 to connect to the NHS ERS API.  Part of the "CreateReferral" method requires an extension like this:

```
"extension": [
      {
        "url": "https://fhir.nhs.uk/STU3/StructureDefinition/Extension-eRS-Shortlist-SearchCriteria-1",
        "valueReference": {
          "reference": "#ServiceSearchCriteria-1"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I can't seem to find a model class that will create this output.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add an extension to an element/resource with the `AddExtension` method. As parameters, you fill in the extension's url and a value of any FHIR datatype. For your extension, that would be a Reference, which is modelled by the `ResourceReference` class:

```
element.AddExtension("https://fhir.nhs.uk/STU3/StructureDefinition/Extension-eRS-Shortlist-SearchCriteria-1",
                     new ResourceReference("#ServiceSearchCriteria-1"));
```

When looking at the referral API, it seems to use FHIR STU3, so you may need to change your library to Hl7.Fhir.Stu3 as well to avoid mismatches in the resource's fields and other version differences. The above method should still work for adding your extension though.

Comment: Thanks Mirjam.  That works perfectly.

I can now create a referral however I do receive the following error from the client:

Operation concluded successfully, but the return status 201 was unexpected

Can I do something to the client so it expects this response as that's what the API returns on success?

Comment: The FhirClient in the SDK apparently expects only '200 OK' or '202 Accepted' answers on operation calls. There is an open issue on the GitHub repo for this (https://github.com/FirelyTeam/firely-net-sdk/issues/2295). As workaround you could do a try..catch around the call, and look at the FhirClient.LastResult and FhirClient.LastBodyAsResource for the result of the operation.